# Need a filter formula for dropdown in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need a formula which need to be add the adjascent values based on the dropdown values.

For Example,

Here I took THB, USD, JPY values as dropdown values. Also I have some adjacent values(Please refer the image attached).

I have B1 & B4 as THB,So, the values at A1 & A4 get added and it need to be stored in D1. Similar to other dropdown values.

In Addition if I change the dropdown values the values which we stored in D column also get changed. PLease find the image here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BjWj.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(B1:B6, C1:C3, A1:A6))
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.